# SignalR in Angular 7 and ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, signalr

I want to use SignalR 2 in my angular app as client and ASP.Net MVC as backend.
I installed `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR` and `Microsoft.Owin` and add `startup.cs` and `ChatHub.cs` like this:
**startup.cs**

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MyMvcApp.Startup))]
namespace MyMvcApp
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

**ChatHub.cs**

```
namespace MyMvcApp.Hubs
{
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public void Send(string user, string message)
        {
            Clients.All.SendMessage(message);
        }
    }
}
```

in my angular app I installed `signalr` npm and included signalr in **angular.json**:

```
"scripts": [
   "node_modules/signalr/jquery.signalR.js"
]
```

and used in **SignalRService**:

```
start() {
    $.connection('http://localhost/hubs').start();
}
```

but I get this error in browser console: `http://localhost/hubs/negotiate?clientProtocol=2.1&_=1557811289416`
How can I fix this?

Comment: I have had a similar toolchain in a project. In my Angular project I used https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR, and in the ASP.NET MVC part the NuGet package _Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb_. This was working fine!

Comment: @mhesabi Can Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR library be used in ASP.NET MVC project? I have similar problem and have not found any example with Angular 6+ and ASP.NET MVC. Any help pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using wrong url. my bad !!!
I had to use `$.connection('http://localhost/signalr').start();` instead of `$.connection('http://localhost/hubs').start();`

Comment: I am having issues with ng2-signalR and Angular 8. I get the error:

`Class constructor Subject cannot be invoked without 'new'
TypeError: Class constructor Subject cannot be invoked without 'new'
    at new BroadcastEventListener (broadcast.event.listener.js:25)`

Answer (score 0):

check in your code if "jsonp: true" is used. If yes, then check it is enabled on hub configuration or not.
Please follow the below link.

https://www.roelvanlisdonk.nl/2013/09/10/asp-net-signalr-self-hosting-fixing-the-error-xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-httplocalhost8080signalrnegotiate-origin-httplocalhost52947-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin/